# Jquery $.post method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi I have a method like this:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult GetPayeesJson(long id)
        {
             ///TODO:
        }
```

Right Now it is being called from a Javascript function like this and works well:

```
$.post("/Payee/GetPayeesJson/" + payerData.Id, null, function (data) {
               fillPayeeCache(data, payerData.Id);
               fillPayeeSelect(payeeCache[payerData.Id]);
            }, "json");
```

In addition to the id that is being passed to the method `GetPayeesJson(long id)` I also want to pass a string that contains the name of the form. So basically I want to make a post call to a method like this:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult GetPayeesJson(long id, string formName)
        {
           //TODO:
        }
```

How I can do this. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Example: Request the test.php page and send some additional data along (while still ignoring the return results).

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to just add formName as a query-string variable to the url in the $.post call.  (ie add "?formName=whatever" to your url)  You could also post it as a form variable named formName.

This behavior is overridable but by default you can use an appropriately named querystring or form variable.

e: offtopic but you should also be able to just use [HttpPost] as the short form of your attribute on the GetPayeesJson method.

e2: more specificity...
adding as querystring -> `"/Payee/GetPayeesJson/" + payerData.Id + "?formName=whateverYourFormIsNamed"`

adding as form var -> see Toast's reply

These will both let you use the syntax for your controller action that you specified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you be more specific. I am using asp.net MVC framework and this call is being passed to a Controller class.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data:  { 
        formName: 'formName' 
    },
    success: function (response) {

    },
    error: function(response, data) {
      alert("Oops... Looks like we're having some difficulties."); 
   }         
});
```

Comment: This defaults to "post" but I think it'd be useful to make it explicit with `type: 'POST'` here since the OP's action method requires it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that info as part of the submitted `data`

so for your specific example

```
$.post("/Payee/GetPayeesJson/" + payerData.Id, 
       {'formName':'value to be passed here'}, 
       function (data) {
               fillPayeeCache(data, payerData.Id);
               fillPayeeSelect(payeeCache[payerData.Id]);
            }, "json");
```

should do what you need..